# ValueError: cannot mix country/category param with sources param

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, valueerror

I am working with an API for the very first time with Python and while doing so I got the following Error:

> *ValueError: cannot mix country/category param with sources param*.

What should I do to solve this Error?

This is the code:

````
import config
from newsapi import NewsApiClient

newsapi = NewsApiClient(api_key=config.api_key)

top_headlines = newsapi.get_top_headlines(q='Neuralink',sources='the-verge',category='technology',language='en',country='us')```
````

Comment: I suggest you review the API documentation. Having said that, the error message seems to be quite clear. Try removing either category or country from the call to get_top_headlines

Comment: @AndyKnight It didn't worked :(. But yeah I will read the docs carefully. Thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official "NewsAPI" {https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/top-headlines} top-headlines docs,
"country" and "category" can not be used simultaneously with "sources" param.